# spring mvc i18n: If key not in properties file, how to set default locale?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, internationalization

suppose if i don't have a key in my one of the properties file i get a exception like :

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.cancel' for locale 'en'.

suppose if it is not available in my messages_ch_CN.properties  is there any way that if it is not present in that file it should check in messages_en_En file.
or is there any work around any one has implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example you have: 2 language

```
messages_ch_CN.properties  /*in the property file lang=Chinese*/
messages_en_EN.properties  /*in the property file lang=English*/
messages.properties  /*in the property file lang=English default*/
```

`messages.properties` this is default property, which always contains every key used throughout your application.

and `NAME-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:com/example/i18n/messages"/>
        <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`<property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>` - says that, if you don't have property `messages_ch_CN.properties` or `messages_en_EN.properties` or in one of those property there is no necessary key, for example: title, spring will use `messages.properties` as default

if `<property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="true"/>` - spring uses user locale of deployment environment, but it not good because user's deployment environment, can different from the languages that we have provided. If user's locale different from the languages that we have provided, spring uses `messages.properties`.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround would be to subclass the `messageSource`  you're using (ie `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`) and override it's `resolveCode()` so that:

- it looks for a message for specified code and locale (by calling `super.resolveCode(code, locale)`).
- if it doesn't find it, then it looks for one with default locale (by calling `super.resolveCode(code, defaultLocale)`).

Then use that newly created class as `messageSource`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18156149/470749 for an actual example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Always provide a default `messages` file (without `locale` specification), which always contains every key used throughout your application. It is not possible to look automatically for another `locale` than the chosen one without subclassing one of the `ResourceBundle`implementations.