# In Java/Spring, how to gracefully handle missing translation values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localization, translation

I'm using Java + Spring for an international website.

The 2 languages are ZH and EN (Chinese and English).

I have 2 files: messages.properties (for English key/value pairs) and messages_zh.properties.

The site is coded in English using #springMessage tags.  I then use Poeditor.com to have translators provide Chinese values for each English phrase.  So, although the English messages.properties file is always complete, and although the messages_zh.properties file always has all of the *keys*, the messages_zh.properties file will sometimes have blank *values* because I receive translations from the translators several days later.

I need my system to display the equivalent English value (on my website) whenever the Chinese value is missing.

How can I tell Spring to "fall back" to use English whenever a Chinese value isn't available?  I need this to happen on a value-by-value basis.

Right now, I see blank button labels on my site wherever a Chinese value is missing.  I'd rather that English (the default language) be used whenever the Chinese is blank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create your own Custom MessageSource for this purpose.

Something like:

```
public class SpecialMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

      @Override
      protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
         MessageFormat result = super.resolveCode(code, locale);
         if (result.getPattern().isEmpty() && locale == Locale.CHINESE) {
            return super.resolveCode(code, Locale.ENGLISH);
         }
         return result;
      }

      @Override
      protected String resolveCodeWithoutArguments(String code, Locale locale) {
         String result= super.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(code, locale);
         if ((result == null || result.isEmpty()) && locale == Locale.CHINESE) {
            return super.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(code, Locale.ENGLISH);
         }
         return result;
      }
   }
```

and  configure this messageSource bean in spring xml as

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="SpecialMessageSource">
.....
</bean>
```

Now to get resolved Label you will be invoking  `MessageSource's` either of the below methods

```
String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale);
String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale);
```

`resolveCode()` will be called when your message label has arguments and you pass those arguments via `args` parameter like below
`invalid.number= {0} is Invalid`
and you invoke `messageSource.getMessage("INVALID_NUMBER", new Object[]{2d}, locale)`

`resolveCodeWithoutArguments()` will be called when your message label does not have arguments and you pass `args` parameter as null
`validation.success = Validation Success`
and you invoke `messageSource.getMessage("INVALID_NUMBER", null, locale)`

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted you, but I'll upvote you and give you credit for the answer since you got me on the right track.  I'm not sure if my code does everything I want.  Maybe you can find problems.

Comment: @Ryan I updated my code and added more explanation as desired by you

Comment: `(result.isEmpty() || result == null)`: Maybe the null check should come before the `isEmpty` check to avoid NPEs :) ... Anyways +1, this answer helped me

Answer (score 2):

@harrybvp's answer got me on the right track.  This is the code that seems to work for me (and is unit-testable when you mock the methods that call "super"):

```
    public class GracefulMessageSource extends org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

        final static private Locale defaultLocale = Locale.ENGLISH;

        @Override protected MessageFormat resolveCode(final String code, final Locale locale) {
            MessageFormat result = superResolveCode(code, locale);

            if (result.toPattern().isEmpty() && !locale.equals(this.defaultLocale)) {
                result = superResolveCode(code, this.defaultLocale);
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override protected String resolveCodeWithoutArguments(final String code, final Locale locale) {
            String result = superResolveCodeWithoutArguments(code, locale);

            if (result.isEmpty() && !locale.equals(this.defaultLocale)) {
                result = superResolveCodeWithoutArguments(code, this.defaultLocale);
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected MessageFormat superResolveCode(final String code, final Locale locale) {
            return super.resolveCode(code, locale);

        }

        protected String superResolveCodeWithoutArguments(final String code, final Locale locale) {
            return super.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(code, locale);

        }

    }
```

and in my webmvc-config.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.mycode.fe.web.GracefulMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>${content.path.config}/WEB-INF/messages</value>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="2"/>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Then in my Velocity view templates:

For a normal key with no arguments: `#springMessage('menu_item1')`

For a key that accepts arguments: `#springMessageText('male_to_female_ratio' [3, 2])`

Then in the messages.properties (English translations):
`male_to_female_ratio = There is a {0}:{1} male-to-female ratio.`