# How to automatically reload messages.properties files in Java/Spring?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I've been working on an interntaional website using Java/Spring using `#springMessage()` tags and `message.properties` files.  See my recent question: [In Java/Spring, how to gracefully handle missing translation values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152710/in-java-spring-how-to-gracefully-handle-missing-translation-values)

I want to be able to edit (overwrite) the messages.properties files and be able to see the new translations immedatiately in my browser (without restarting Tomcat).

I thought that http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html#Automatic_Reloading would be what I need, but I'm not sure how to edit my webmvc-config.xml to use that.

Comment: Reloading the properties file might not be enough. If any of your beans depend on values in the file, then they have to be recreated. This means scraping the application context and refreshing it, regenerating all the beans inside it. It's probably best to do that by restart the app. What you can do instead is have a configuration class that refers to a configuration file not handled by Spring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.  It worked after I edited webmvc-config.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>${content.path.config}/WEB-INF/messages</value>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="2"/>
</bean>
```

(I just needed to add the cacheSeconds property.)