# Resource bundle defaults to parent message

Tags: java, spring, properties, internationalization

I have an English resource bundle `messages.properties` and a German resource bundle `messages_de.properties`.

When I don't find a message in German bundle, but it's present in English bundle, `REsourceBundle#getString()` method returns the message from English (it's set as German bundle's parent).

I want to temporarily disable this behavior when I am testing in which scenarios German messages are missing, so basically **I want to throw an exception when a German message is not found**, but English message is present (in my specific test environment).

What's the easiest way to do this? We are using Spring and looking up messages through application context.

In the image below, it shows how ResourceBundle implementation looks up in the parent map if it doesn't find it in itself (and there seems no simple way to change this behavior).

[image: ResourceBundle with Parent]

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152710/in-java-spring-how-to-gracefully-handle-missing-translation-values/18156149#18156149) may help you.

Comment: This is what we do by default...I just want a clean way to disable this falling back. But ResourceBundle doesn't give any simple way to do this. :(

Comment: Got it working by using PropertyResourceBundle#handleGetObject()

Comment: @Sumedh how did you configure it to fall back to english when the german properties file did not contain the key?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to set `fallbackToSystemLocale` property of `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` to `false`.

Comment: We have our own MessageSource implementation, but it uses ResourceBundle#getString() and not Properties api. ResourceBundle always falls back on parent, which I want to disable, but don't see any way. :(